# What's the purpose of a React Functional Component when it can be used to modify state?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and learning it. From [this](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/react-functional-components-vs-class-components-86a2d2821a22) link:

> There are mainly two components in React:
>
> - Functional Components also known as Stateless component
> - Class Component also known as Stateful component

and it seems that functional components are the rage these days e.g., I inherited some code and it uses functional components everywhere. The same article is then saying:

> ... a functional component is just a plain JavaScript function, we
> cannot use setState() method inside component. That’s why they also
> get called functional stateless components. ... **useState can be used
> to store state in a functional component**.

and I do see tons of code using `useState` in functional components to modify state. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Functional components were referred to as stateless components but its no longer correct to think of them as stateless. [This](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) link from official documentation explains it:

> You might have previously known these as “stateless components”. We’re
> now introducing the ability to use React state from these, so we
> prefer the name “function components”.

To answer the second part of the question, functional components are indeed the rage these days because that's the official guidance and recommendation. From [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both) page:

> In the longer term, we expect Hooks to be the primary way people write
> React components.

Also see [this](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/) page for some background and comparison of class components vs. functional components.